# How do I drag item/file from ArcCatalog to custom UI form created with Toolbar Add-in?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, add-in, arccatalog

I have created a button add-in in ArcMap that pops up custom UI/Form. I want to drag and drop file from ArcCatalog into the textbox on the Form. I am able to do so with windows explorer but not from ArcCatalog.

I'm writing code using C#. When I drag the file from catalog, I am sure DataFormats type is not FileDrop. Any suggestions?

```c#
private void openShapeFileTextBox_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy; // Okay
        }
        else
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None; // Unknown data, ignore it
        }
        nameTextbox.Text = temp;
    }
```